# notifyDataSetChanged method is not refreshing listview using updated data?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using an **ArrayAdapter** with **filterable** interface to implement search functionality in a listview.My code for adapter is following:

```
public class FlightsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flight> implements Filterable {

    List<Flight> flightLists = new ArrayList<Flight>();
    private List<Flight> origFlightList;
    private Context context;
    Flight flight = null;

    public FlightsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Flight> fLists) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, fLists);
        this.context = context;
        this.flightLists = fLists;
    }

    public void updateFlightList(List<Flight> newData){
        this.flightLists.clear();
        this.flightLists = newData;

    }
public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final List<Flight> results = new ArrayList<Flight>();
                if (origFlightList == null)
                    origFlightList = flightLists;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (origFlightList != null && origFlightList.size() > 0) {
                        for (final Flight f : origFlightList) {
                            if (f.getPlace().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(f);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size();
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                flightLists = (ArrayList<Flight>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

**getFilter()** and **publishResults()** methods get triggered properly on searching and **flightLists** get populated with new data but the listview remain same with no items change, I don't know what I am doing wrong in above code, Please help me figure out this problem

Comment: Have you tried notifyDataSetInvalide()?

Comment: @KarnShah yes but no change at all :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
 flightLists = (ArrayList<Flight>) results.values;
```

Replace this with

```
flightLists.clear();
flightLists.addAll((ArrayList<Flight>) results.values);
```

See if that fixes your issue.

Later edit (explanation):

When you created your adapter, you gave it a List object. The adapter thus has a reference, a pointer, to that List, from where it takes the data to display.

When you have replaced that reference with a whole other block of memory

```
flightLists = (ArrayList<Flight>) results.values;
```

the adapter didn't updated the orignial data set (from where it actually was taking data to display). Thus, notifyDataSetChanged() didn't work.

When updating the data in an adapter, you **have to** keep the original data structure reference intact. Clearing and populating with another data set is an option. Reinstantiating it (in any way) isn't.

This is basic java.

Comment: its working but I want to understand what's the problem in my code, could you please explain?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.